# MissingPlugin Implementation for the plugin record_mp3 FLUTTER

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, audio-recording

When recording the audio using [record_mp3](https://pub.dev/packages/record_mp3) it give the UnhandledException: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method  record mp3.

the code was simple as documentation says :
`

```
if (await hasPermission() ) {
  RecordMp3.instance.start(widget.path, (type) {
    // record fail callback
  });

  bool isRecording =  RecordMp3.instance.status == RecordStatus.RECORDING ? true : false;
  setState(() {
    _isRecording = isRecording;
    _recordDuration = 0;
  });

  _startTimer();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I Found a way to solve this,

in your MainActivity.kt file in android/app/src/kotlin you have to add the plugin that you've used like in this case just import the plugin and then get it in the MainActivity class like this :

```
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import com.plugin.record_mp3.RecordMp3Plugin
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(RecordMp3Plugin())


  }
}
```